# Install Ubuntu to external HDD from a current Ubuntu installation?

Tags: system-installation

I'd like to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a USB HDD.  I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on my internal HDD - can I just plug the external drive in and run the installer from my current OS?  I haven't found any info on how to do that, but it seems like I shouldn't need to reboot just to install an OS on an unused HDD.

Comment: Nope. Any method you use that is done with the current system active is likely to corrupt your destination.

Comment: Why is that?  If I tell the installer to use /dev/sdb I don't see why it would care what's going on with /dev/sda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using VirtualBox, based on https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box.

Basically, I did

```
sudo chown me:me /dev/sdb
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/file.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdb
```

Then I created a VM, attached the install DVD and added a HDD from an existing file (`file.vmdk`).  I set the "mode" for the HDD to "writethrough" (File->Virtual Media Manager->file.vmdk->modify).  Also if you intend to boot from the disk on an EFI system be sure to enable EFI in VirtualBox (check the "use EFI" box in the VM's settings) so the installer creates the appropriate partitions.

This approach is nice because it lets me install and setup the OS from my current OS - no need for another computer to look things up in case something goes wrong, I can do other work while I wait for things to install, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> but it seems like I shouldn't need to reboot just to install an OS on an unused HDD

Have you ever seen a method from any OS creators on how to do that?  I have not. Well not yet.

You can create an exact copy from 1 partition to another partition with ...

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

where `if` is the partition to copy and `of` the destination that is to be created. The sdX and the sdY need to be changed to the proper device (check with `fdisk -l`). Typing the wrong device will erase that device without any warnings.

Using the normal reboot with live session install is by far the more adviced method.

Warnings

- do this with an active system and your destination can become corrupt: the active system will write to your partition during the copy and if that happens while content is being copied ... you get a destination that is not an exact copy where the damage can be be fatal for the new setup
- sdY is going to be overwritten and there is not a way back from it.

Besides the manual method: [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) is made for this

> What is Clonezilla?
>
> Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program similar to True Image® or Norton Ghost®. It helps you to do system deployment, bare metal backup and recovery. Three types of Clonezilla are available, Clonezilla live, Clonezilla lite server, and Clonezilla SE (server edition). Clonezilla live is suitable for single machine backup and restore. While Clonezilla lite server or SE is for massive deployment, it can clone many (40 plus!) computers simultaneously. Clonezilla saves and restores only used blocks in the hard disk. This increases the clone efficiency. With some high-end hardware in a 42-node cluster, a multicast restoring at rate 8 GB/min was reported.

But ... even they use a live session method.

Comment: Thanks, but the goal is to do a fresh install of a new OS so cloning isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

### Another VirtualBox method to install to USB drive

You Can do a Full install to USB drive from Ubuntu using Virtual Box.

- From Ubuntu install VirtualBox if you do not already have it.
- Start VBox and make a new Ubuntu machine.
- Start the Ubuntu machine and point it at the Ubuntu iso file.
- When the process gets to the Try/Install window select "Try".
- Plug in your USB and confirm it is visible to VBox.
- Select the Install Ubuntu icon on the desktop.
- When you get to partitioning select "Something else"
- Select the USB as target for the install.
- Continue the installation as normal until complete.

I have tried this with the latest versions of Ubuntu and VirtualBox. (and with previous versions of each.